# Execute and complete google maps geocode before allowing submit to continue

Tags: jquery, google-maps, backbone.js, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a backbone view with some form validation. The form validation uses preventDefault if the form has errors. If it doesn't it should take the value in the input field, retrieve lat,lng and populate two hidden field before submit is allowed to continue. I am trying to use a deferred, but not sure what I've got wrong. I've cut out some unnecessary bits here and there to make it cleaner to post here.

I've tried using preventDefault with the deferred (which I shouldn't have to anyway correct?), but submitting again is a bit of a challenge using the submit event.

Without preventdefault the lat,lng fields are not updated before submit. Perhaps wrong implementation of deferred/promise or when using preventdefault the submit triggers the validation again and I end up in a loop. I don't want to use setTimeout because I don't want to delay the user any longer than getting the response back.

```
events: {
  'submit': 'validateForm'
},
validateForm: function(e){

//lotsa validation then

  var loc = $('#location').length;
  if ( loc ){  
    var parent = $(e.currentTarget).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.when(this.getCoordinates(e))
    .done(function(){
      parent.submit();
    });
  }
},

getCoordinates : function(e) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var that = this;
    var parent = $(e.currentTarget).closest('form');
    var addr =  parent.find('#location').val();

    if ($.trim(addr).length) {
        var apiurl = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addr '&bounds=' + bounds + '';
        $.ajax({
            url : apiurl,
            dataType : 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {

            try {
                if(!data.results.length){
                    return;
                }
                var coord = data.results[0].geometry.location;
                var result = data.results[0].formatted_address;
                if (coord) {
                    var lat = coord.lat;
                    var lon = coord.lng;

                    parent.find("input[data-geo-type = 'lat']").val(lat);
                    parent.find("input[data-geo-type = 'lng']").val(lon);
                    deferred.resolve();
                }

            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }).fail(function () {
             $(e.currentTarget).val(addr);
        });
    } else {
       deferred.reject(); 
    }
return deferred.promise();
},
```

Any help or pointers appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is `validateForm` not triggering the form submit? or something else? What is `submitCoordinates` doing here?

Comment: `submitCoordinates()` or `getCoordinates()`? Also curly braces are out of balance. Fix the question then maybe someone can provide an answer.

Comment: I fixed the method name and bracket. Without preventdefault the lat,lng fields are not updated before submit. Perhaps wrong implementation of deferred/promise or when using preventdefault the submit triggers the validation again and I end up in a loop. I don't want to use setTimeout because I don't want to delay the user any longer than getting the response back. Thanks,

Comment: You're not resolving/rejecting if `$.trim(addr).length` is false.

Comment: additionally, `parent.submit()` will retrigger the submit event, possibly causing an infinite loop. Are you experiencing an infinite loop? (you would see it continously getting coordinates from google in your network tab)

Comment: No, `form.submit()` very deliberately doesn't trigger the form's submit event for that very reason. It's been that way since the very early days of HTML/javascript.

Comment: @MrBrimm, code is a bit confusing. `e.currentTarget` would only be the address field, if `validateForm()` was called in a very particular way.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have changed the addr var but the geocoding doesnt complete before submit with preventDeafault removed and I end up in a loop if I leave it on. Thanks

Comment: @KevinB you are right about the loop. Not sure how to solve that one. I added a reject, but I'm still not sure why it's not working even when addr.length is true. Thanks.

Comment: If it is looping, then the solution is easy: replace `.submit()` with `[0].submit()`. this will allow you to bypass any bound events and instead just perform the action.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 That is true, unless, you're calling `.submit()` on a jquery object which is the case here. jQuery will instead trigger the event, and only after all the events have been triggered, will it submit, and only if none of the events returned false or prevented default.

Comment: @KevinB that did the trick. I had tried that before, but you made me re-look at it and I realized I was getting submit is not a function because the dang submit button had the id="submit". I changed the id and it's Working now. Thanks!

Comment: hahaha, yeah that's a common mistake too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're likely running into an infinite loop due to your inner `parent.submit()`. Since `parent` is a jQuery object, it's re-triggering all of the events, thus causing the ajax to happen again, infinitely. Fortunately, the solution is simple. Instead of calling `.submit()` on the jQuery object, call it on the form itself. You'll also have to make sure that you don't have `id="submit"` anywhere. By calling it directly on the form, you'll just submit the form without triggering any events.

```
validateForm: function(e){

//lotsa validation then

  var loc = $('#location').length;
  if ( loc ){  
    var parent = $(e.currentTarget).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.when(this.getCoordinates(e))
    .done(function(){
      //parent.submit();
      parent[0].submit();/* modified line */
    });
  }
},
```